# Registering custom post type wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have created new post type in my theme but when i try to get to the permalink for the post, it give me that the post not found

```
function my_post_type_news() {

    register_post_type( 'news',
            array( 
            'label' => __('News'), 
            'public' => true, 
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'news',
                'with_front' => FALSE,
            ),
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'editor',
                    'excerpt')
                ) 
            );

 register_taxonomy('news_category', 'news', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'News Categories', 'singular_name' => 'Category', "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true));
      }

     add_action('init', 'my_post_type_news');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_post_type_news() {

register_post_type( 'news',
        array( 
        'label' => __('News'), 
        'public' => true, 
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'rewrite' =>false,
        'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'thumbnail',
                'editor',
                'excerpt')
            ) 
        );
```

register_taxonomy('news_category', 'news', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'News Categories', 'singular_name' => 'Category', "rewrite" => true, "query_var" => true));
      }

```
 add_action('init', 'my_post_type_news');
```

Use above function, it will works. I have changed rewrite as false.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but why ? could you explain to me ?